# "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable" for keywords= inside a list

Tags: python, syntax

I am going to put a very easy example of what I'm trying to do before posting my code

example 1:
This is what I want to accomplish(but with the keywords inside a list)

```py
print("hi", end="****")
output: hi ****
```

example 2:
This is as far as I can make it work

```
keyword = end="****"
print("hi", keyword)
output: hi ****
```

example 2:
This is where it  fails

```py
keywords = ['spam', end="****"]
print("hi", keywords[1])

output: keywords = ['spam', end="****"]
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

example 2.1:
This is where it  fails (on a similar but different approach)

although, this works

```py
keyword = end="****"
keywords = ['spam', keyword]
print("hi", keywords[1])
output: hi ****
```

this one doesn't work:

```py
keyword = sep="^^^^", end="****"
keywords = ['spam', keyword]
print("hi", keywords[1])

output: keyword = sep="^^^^", end="****"
                     ^
    SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

and this is my code:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression 
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

LogisticRegression_args = None
KNeighborsClassifier_args = n_neighbors=5
GaussianNB_args = None
DecisionTreeClassifier_args = criterion='entropy'
SVC_args = kernel='linear'
SVC_non_linear_args = kernel='rgb'
RandomForestClassifier_args = criterion='entropy', n_estimators=10, random_state=0

basic_classifier_models = [[[LogisticRegression], [LogisticRegression_args], ['LogisticRegression:']], [[KNeighborsClassifier], [KNeighborsClassifier_args], ['KNeighborsClassifier:']],
                           [[GaussianNB], [GaussianNB_args], ['GaussianNB:']], [[DecisionTreeClassifier], [DecisionTreeClassifier_args], ['DecisionTreeClassifier:']],
                           [[SVC], [SVC_args], ['SVC:']], [[SVC], [SVC_non_linear_args], ['Non_linear SVC:']],
                           [[RandomForestClassifier], [RandomForestClassifier_args], ['RandomForestClassifier:']]]

output: RandomForestClassifier_args = criterion='entropy', n_estimators=10, random_state=0
                                               ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

Comment: Use single quote around like keywords = ['spam', 'end="****"']

Comment: `keyword = end="****"` sets two variables. `keyword = "****"` and `end = "****"`. It does not do what you think it does.

Comment: either go with dictionary`keyword = {sep:"^^^^", end:"****"}` or separate new line `keyword = sep="^^^^"     end="****"]`

Comment: by this `RandomForestClassifier_args = criterion='entropy', n_estimators=10, random_state=0` are trying to bind them with `RandomForestClassifier_args `? if so, go with dicttionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`keyword = end="****"` sets two variables. `keyword = "****"` and `end = "****"`. It does not do what you think it does. Your second example prints what it does because it is equivalent to calling `print("hi", "****")`

To specify arguments without actually writing them in the function call, you can do it by [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

You specify positional arguments by unpacking a list like so:

```
args = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(*args)
# Output: a b c
```

Or, for keyword args, you unpack a dict like so:

```
kwargs = { "end": "****\n" }
print("abc", **kwargs)
Output: abc****
```

You can even do both:

```
args = ["hello", "world"]
kwargs = { "sep": "|", "end": "***\n" }
print(*args, **kwargs)
# Equivalent to print("hello", "world", sep="|", end="***\n")
# Output: hello|world***
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a variable in a list. Here's how you could make this function work (assuming I read the question right)

```
keywords = ['spam', "****"]
print("hi", keywords[1])
```

if you're trying to find a word in a sequence, which is what I'm assuming this is trying to accomplish, you can do so easily by doing the following for loop:

```
check = "hi"
for item in keywords:
    if check.find(item) != -1:
        print("keyword found in input")
```